# How do I reverse a checkbox state to make it unchecked (AngularJS)?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-click, angularjs-ng-change

I basically want that when the user clicks on a checkbox, their decision is immediately reversed and the checkbox is unchecked. The code below is not working. I tried other variations like value = !value instead of value = false and tried initializing another controller variable to be equal to the checkbox variable and changing the other controller variable. None of this works; basically, I cannot set the checkbox state unless the application is first being initialized.

HTML code:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="avariabledefinedincontroller" ng-click="changemystate(avariabledefinedincontroller)">
```

Controller code:

```
$scope.avariabledefinedincontroller = false;


$scope.changemystate = function(value){
  if (value == true) {
    value = false;

 }

 else {
   value = value;
 }

};
```

Comment: avariabledefinedincontroller will automatically goes to true or false.  Why you want a function to that.

Comment: If you want to prevent the user from using the checkbox, why not just disable it?

Comment: use ng-checked="scopevar" ng-click="scopevar = !scopevar" and ofcourse initialize $scope.scopevar in the controller

Comment: My whole point is there are 6 checkboxes. On clicking the 5th, it should be unchecked. I have detailed code for that. Should I repost with all the code with all the checkboxes mentioned? It is important that the scope variable should be changed by the value passed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value passed into `changemystate` will be the value the checkbox has when it is clicked. So if you want it to stay at that value, you can set up a timeout to restore it to that value. No negation is needed.

Also, assigning a value to `value` will do nothing. You have to modify the scope variable. If you want to identify the scope variable for the item that was clicked, you can pass in a string:

```js
function MyController($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.mybool = false;

  $scope.changemystate = function(key) {
     var value = $scope[key];
     $timeout(function () {
         $scope[key] = value;
     }, 0);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MyController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="mybool" ng-click="changemystate('mybool')" />
  {{mybool}}
</div>
```

Comment: You are right about the scope variable, but the problem is I have 6 checkboxes and want the 5th one checked (only 4 at a time). I shared only general code here. If a value passed in can be changed, that is my goal.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need a function for that :

*In the template :*

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="avariabledefinedincontroller" />
```

*And in the controller, you'll have just the variable :*

```
// Default state
$scope.avariabledefinedincontroller = false;
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/micaz/sez92ju2/4/)**

---

**Edit :** The purpose of this question was actually to *prevent* the user to check a checkbox, but without disabling the checkbox. For that, @JLRishe's answer addresses well the problem, though I would personally add the state value to set as an argument to `setState` :

```js
angular.module('demoApp', []).controller('DemoController', function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.myVar = false;

  $scope.setState = function (varName, val) {
    $timeout(function() {
        $scope[varName] = val;  
    }, 0);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myVar" ng-click="setState('myVar', false)" />
  {{myVar}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

VYou can also use a short-hand:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="avariabledefinedincontroller" ng-click="aVariable = !aVariable"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of options available to you, but just in case this can help someone, I did two things.

- I passed the $event in so that I could run event.preventDefault() (so it wont get checked)

  1. `ng-click="changemystate($event, avariabledefinedincontroller)">`
  2. In $scope.changemystate() I then added the event param, and called
     `event.preventDefault()`
- Secondly, I then just added a `return` so that the method terminates, so there is no need to roll back the value, because it prevents it from being updated in the first place.